# Replacement async-await to then

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I tried to remove async await from code

```
before(async () => {
  await tests.env();
  token = await tests.getToken(accMock, 'acceptor');
});
```

My attempt:

```
tests.env()
  .then((output) => output.getToken(accMock, 'acceptor')
  .then((v) => (token = v)));
```

But this code does not pass the tests. What can be wrong?

Comment: _"Replasunf"_ - Nice title... :|

Comment: But why go "back" from `async/await` to the traditional `Promise/then` approach? It should be the other way around

Comment: Did you try `return test.env...`? Your before might not be waiting for test to actually be resolved?

Comment: `.then(() => tests.getToken(accMock, 'acceptor'))`

Answer (score 1):

The two pieces of code are not equivalent. Your first piece of code is:

```
before(async () => {
  await tests.env();
  token = await tests.getToken(accMock, 'acceptor');
});
```

Your second piece of code, rewritten with async/await is:

```
before(async () => {
  let output = await tests.env();
  let v = await output.getToken(accMock, 'acceptor');
  token = v;
});
```

Note that in the first code you're calling `tests.getToken()` but in the second you're calling `output.getToken()`.

The correct re-write is:

```
before(() => {
  return tests.env()
              .then(() => tests.getToken(accMock, 'acceptor'))
              .then(v => token = v);
});
```